# How do you force AWS lambda trigger off of SQS consistently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We noticed that when setting up an AWS lambda to trigger from SQS that a lot of times the trigger happens minutes and sometimes up to an hour delay to trigger. I know AWS lambda does polling internally and when the queue is empty it probably does some exponential backoff.

However, we have a scheduler that runs every 30 min and pushes data into the queue. However, lambda is triggered much much later for a % of messages. Our business requirement that it triggers within a min.

Is there a way to force lambda to check the queue consistently? An alternative was to uses step functions but this is not possible due to another answer in this thread --> [How do you run functions in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523247/how-do-you-run-functions-in-parallel/54523686#54523686)

I was also thinking about pushing data into s3 and have lambda trigger from s3 asynchronously vs being polled but s3 does not have a batch api when we want to push a lot of records so that's out.

Comment: Random delays you are seeing may be because of the concurrency limit of the account or lambda itself. I've been using SQS trigger for a while and to be honest I never experienced any delay of more than a fews seconds. Did you look into CloudWatch metric specifically lambda concurrency?

Comment: Just checked. Metrics show Max of 100. I have a limit of 5000.

Comment: hmmm I'm finding it really hard to believe that trigger is taking up to an hour so when you've already confirmed its not concurrency issue. Do you have any custom config in your SQS queue? How do you find out that there is a delay? Do you log the time when messages are being pushed to SQS and did you check Lambda CloudWatch during the delay period? Was there any activity?

Comment: If I publish a message during quiet time, then I get the message.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be the wrong use of async/await when using AWS SDK. They only support .promise(). That was the reason that not all messages ended up in sqs.

Hope it helps others. AWS is working on a new sdk that will support async/await. Here is the link for their 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/153#issuecomment-457769969

Answer (score -1):

I would check to make sure the SQS is either long pulling or short pulling.

"In almost all cases, Amazon SQS long polling is preferable to short polling. Long-polling requests let your queue consumers receive messages as soon as they arrive in your queue while reducing the number of empty ReceiveMessageResponse instances returned.

Amazon SQS long polling results in higher performance at reduced cost in the majority of use cases. However, if your application expects an immediate response from a ReceiveMessage call, you might not be able to take advantage of long polling without some modifications to your application.

For example, if your application uses a single thread to poll multiple queues, switching from short polling to long polling will probably not work, because the single thread will wait for the long-poll timeout on any empty queues, delaying the processing of any queues that might contain messages.

In such an application, it is a good practice to use a single thread to process only one queue, allowing the application to take advantage of the benefits that Amazon SQS long polling provides."

Also, if you're looking to fire off your lambda function, could you set up an SNS notification system to your SQS? Something along the lines of SQS  SNS  Lambda. This should get you sub minute and you're not constantly pulling the queue for messages. You'll just do it on a SNS.

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/

Comment: OP is using SQS Lambda trigger so application polling is irrelevant. AWS Lambda service does the long-polling on customer behalf.

Comment: My concurrency barely hits 100, my unreserved limited was also upped to 5000. No changes, still see delays. I think it may be because the queue sit empty for 28 out of 30 min so lambda does not poll right away. Not sure.

Comment: @TimJohnson there's nothing documented about Lambda not polling the queue during quiet time, but there's an SQS metric called [`NumberOfEmptyReceives`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) that will show you whether polling is indeed occurring -- it increments every time a poll finishes without finding any visible messages.

Comment: Thank you. I will look. I have seen the docs that talk about point being delayed during quiet time specifically with concurrency